# Change an Outlook reply/forward message when composing using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

When replying, forwarding (or basically doing any sort of response to an email item), I would like to change the body of the email. I know how to do this on the "send" event, but I would rather do this before composing so I can see change.
Using send:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RegX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegX
        .pattern = "[a regular expression that I want to fix in the email body]"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
    End With
    Select Case Item.BodyFormat
        Case olFormatHTML
            Item.HTMLBody = RegX.Replace(Item.HTMLBody, "")
        Case Else
            'olFormatPlain, olFormatRichText, lFormatUnspecified?
            Item.Body = RegX.Replace(Item.Body, "")
    End Select
End Sub
```

I found a way to trigger the compose event in the external windows (Inspectors.NewInspector) but have difficulty finding a transparent way that includes a reply composed in the inline editor in Outlook 2016 (Explorer.InlineResponse);

Here's what works for the "popped out" modal windows response:

```vb
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Public WithEvents myOlInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlInspectors = myOlApp.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub myOlInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    Set Item = Inspector.CurrentItem
    Set RegX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegX
        .pattern = "[a regular expression that I want to fix in the email body]"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
    End With
    Select Case Item.BodyFormat
        Case olFormatHTML
            Item.HTMLBody = RegX.Replace(Item.HTMLBody, "")
        Case Else
            'olFormatPlain, olFormatRichText, lFormatUnspecified?
            Item.Body = RegX.Replace(Item.Body, "")
    End Select
End Sub
```

How can we do something similar that also works in the inline editor, preferably using a transparent single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inline replies, you can try to use Explorer.InlineReponse event - the Item will be passed as a parameter.

Example of this in action:

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Public WithEvents myOlExplorer As Outlook.Explorer

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlExplorer = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub myOlExplorer_InlineResponse(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' do things to the Item here in the inline response
End Sub
```