# Reply Inline With a Outlook Template

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to reply to a message inline with a outlook template using a macro.

I am currently using the below code to perform the reply with a template but this opens a pop out reply window.

```
  Sub Reply_Scripting()
    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem
    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Test.oft")
    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.Display
End Sub
```

I have searched and found there has been similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796134/change-an-outlook-reply-forward-message-when-composing-using-vba). However, I was not able to modify the code to make it work successfully in my case.

Thanks.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what do you mean by "inline" ? Do you _not_ want to see the reply window ? I use a script for an auto-reply with a standard generic reply the sends automatically without opening the reply.

Comment: Yes, I would like to insert a template without opening a new popup out window while replying and also be able to edit it before sending it.https://imgur.com/a/2TCrD

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the following line of code:

```
 replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.reply.HTMLBody
```

Note, you need to get a well formed HTML markup and assign it to the `HTMLBody` property. But it looks like you try to merge two HTML pages into a single one by adding one to another.

Instead, you need to paste the body content of the template you are loading in the code at the beginning of the body section of the existing item. I.e. right after the `<body>` tag.

Comment: If possible, could you please show me how to go about doing it? I only have limited understanding of the working of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for an "auto reply". This **DOES NOT** allow editing before sending, but easily modified to do so. See comments in code.

```
Sub ReplyMSG()
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply

  For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
      olItem.UnRead = False        '<<----This marks the email as Read
   Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll   '<<----This replies to all recipients
        olReply.HTMLBody = "Insert a message or template here" & olReply.HTMLBody
    olReply.Display '<<-----Use this to display the email before sending

    olReply.Send    '<<-----Comment this out if you want to edit before sending
  Next olItem
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch, but this still pops out a separate reply window.